# powershell adding office 365 mailbox for on prem created user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, powershell-3.0

I used to have a script that created a user in our on prem AD, allowed this user to sync/Replicate to our cloud environment, and then attach an office 365mailbox to this user.
I did this using following code:

```
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@domain.com", $pass
                    Connect-MsolService -credential $LiveCred

                    $AccountSku = Get-MsolAccountSku
                    If ($AccountSku[1].ActiveUnits -ge $AccountSku[1].ConsumedUnits) {
                        Set-MsolUser –UserPrincipalName usermailbox@domain.com –UsageLocation BE 
                        Set-MsolUserLicense –UserPrincipalName usermailbox@domain.com -AddLicenses LICENSENAME
                    }
```

However Connect-MSolService has been or is close to being deprecated.  It still works on my own pc, but is no longer working on the server this was running.

I am now told to use the new EXO V3 powershell to do mailbox actions.  However i do not seem to find the correct command/syntax to do what i want it to do.
Namely:
Create/attach a new mailbox to an already existing user (without mailbox at that point)
I tried using this:

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline
New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName UserMailbox@domain.com
```

documentation told me UserPrincipalName was a valid argument, but it does not seem to be the case.  Using onlineservicesId does not work either

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the error is, but `New-Mailbox` creates a user object and mailbox. To create a mailbox for an existing user you use the [`Enable-Mailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/enable-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet.